# boost::python and swig integration

Tags: c++, python, swig, boost-python

I have two classes, the first called "Radish" and the second called "RadishCont".
All the code is written in C++ and need to be used in python.

Radish have been exposed to python using SWIG; RadishCont, instead, have been exposed using boost::python.

I need to add a method into the class RadishCont that has this syntax:

```
Radish* get_radish()
{
    return &radish;
}
```

Where "radish" is a Radish instance contained in RadishCont.

When I execute the python code I receive this exception:

```
TypeError: No Python class registered for C++ class Radish
```

So, my question is: how can I make this method work in python without rewriting RadishCont using SWIG ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, I have done it.

I have created a class instance in my boost python module like this:

```
class_<Radish>("Radish");
```

I have created a converter function like this:

```
static void* radishConvert(PyObject* obj)
{
    char thisStr[] = "this";
    //first we need to get the this attribute from the Python Object
    if (!PyObject_HasAttrString(obj, thisStr))
            return NULL;

    PyObject* thisAttr = PyObject_GetAttrString(obj, thisStr);
    if (thisAttr == NULL)
            return NULL;
    //This Python Object is a SWIG Wrapper and contains our pointer
    void* pointer = ((PySwigObject*)thisAttr)->ptr;
    Py_DECREF(thisAttr);
    return pointer;
}
```

Where PySwigObject is a struct like this:

```
struct PySwigObject 
{
    PyObject_HEAD 
    void * ptr;
    const char * desc;
};
```

Last, I have registered my converter:

```
boost::python::converter::registry::insert(&radishConvert, type_id<Radish>());
```

This perfectly works, I can get objects from SWIG and pass it to boost::python. The inverse process is still unsolved but is enough for me.

This is the guide I have used to find the solution:
    http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/HowTo#SWIG_exposed_C.2B-.2B-_object_from_Python

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that you are better off rewriting your SWIG interface to include the new function. SWIG uses a internal registration system for classes/functions which is not compatible with boost::pythons system (or at least not out of the box).

Answer (score 0):

That error comes from Boost.Python. BP's type table has no entry for Radish. Without an entry, there is no way for BP to know what to do. The only way to get an entry is to wrap Radish in BP.

I am afraid that BP and SWIG were simply not made to work together, and a very much doubt that you will get them to work the way you want, with out extensive hacking.

I recommend that you move your entire system to either one library, or the other